# var() keeps returning NA or NaN R

Tags: r, nan, var

I am trying to compute the variance for a variable in my data frame, var(df$var) keeps returning NA or NaN however. the variable is the ratio between two original variables; FOODperINC = FOODexp / TOTALINC

var() of FOODexp and TOTALINC do return numbers.

I have searched and tried the following:

> remove NA's from original variables and FOODperINC.
>
> add 1 to TOTALING, to avoid dividing over 0
>
> var(as.numeric()) / var(as.vector())

I do not quite understand why I can;t compute the variance. What am I doing wrong?

My code for reference:

```
df4 = df3[!is.na(df3$FOODTOT.x),]
df4 = df4[!is.na(df4$FINCAFTM.x),]


df4$FINCAFTM.x = df4$FINCAFTM.x +1
df4$INCperFOOD = df4$FOODTOT.x / df4$FINCAFTM.x

df3$SEAperINC.x = df3$SEAFOOD.x / df3$FINCAFTM.x
df3$FOODperINC.x = df3$FOODTOT.x / df3$FINCAFTM.x

var.test(df3$FOODperINC.x, df3$SEAperINC.x)

var(df4$FOODperINC.x)


var(df3$SEAperINC.x, na.rm=T)
var(as.numeric(df4$FOODperINC.x), na.rm=T)
which(is.null(df4$FOODperINC.x))

cov(df5$SEAperINC.x, df3$FOODperINC.x)
View(df4$FOODperINC.x)
```

Comment: Please add your code as text and not as an image, otherwise I cannot be parsed by search engines and copied by other users.

Comment: [“In God we Trust, all others must bring data”-W.Deming](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-in-God-we-trust-rest-bring-data) . Could you post the output of `dput(head(df3,5))` and `dput(head(df4,5))`

Comment: Thank you! I haven't put the whole output (its 2 times ±850 vars) but as I read the tail it was clear right away.

Comment: Piggy back-question:  does this (from dput(head()): CEREAL.x = c(0, 0, 0, 3.65126, 13.31), mean that different values are contained for each observation in this variable? or does it just list the first 5 observations of the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brainfart;

```
df4$INCperFOOD != df4$FOODperINC
```

Thank you Ossan!

```
"INCperFOOD", "FOODperINC", "FOODperINC.x",), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```